# Can Apple Watch correctly count steps when hand is holding dog leash or flashlight? ⌚️ 

Tags: apple-watch

Both my hands are often occupied while on long dog walks. Think dog leash, flashlight, hot tea, warming in pocket, etc.

Will the Apple Watch still be able to count steps with some accuracy? Or is that an unreasonable expectation when my arm is not swinging in stride?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Apple Watch will still count steps in those circumstances. Even though you're carrying a flash light or you have your hands in your pockets, you're still moving about - and the accelerometer in the watch will be able to detect footfalls and consequently steps.

There are some cases where the Apple Watch doesn't count steps, or have a really hard time counting accurately. For example if you're walking with a pram or stroller, where your hands are resting on the handle, which will minimize any input to the accelerometer from your walking.

In general, I would recommend that you calibrate your Apple Watch to suit the way you take your walks/runs. Follow Apple's instructions here for calibration:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204516

The steps are:

1. On your iPhone, open the Settings app
2. Tap Privacy > Location Services
3. Make sure that Location Services is turned on
4. Scroll down, then tap System Services
5. Make sure that Motion Calibration & Distance is turned on
6. On your Apple Watch, go to a flat, open outdoor area that offers good GPS reception
7. Open the Workout app. To start, tap Outdoor Walk or Outdoor Run
8. Walk or run at your normal pace for about 20 minutes